# Record tests screencast with C# + WebDriver + NUnit

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I use C# (Visual Studio) + WebDriver + NUnit to write UI tests for Web application.
Could someone recommend me a way to record tests screencast **except Microsoft Expression Encoder 4**"?

Comment: There is a few .Net Core answers using FFmpeg over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424616/how-to-record-test-execution-using-selenium-c-sharp-in-netcore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was solved with AForge.Video + AForge.Video.FFMPEG

Comment: Care to elaborate on how you were able to use those tools to accomplish the task?

Comment: I've added mentioned .dlls to project. Then created VideoRecorder class with Start and Stop methods and call them inside SetUp and TearDown methods. Can share VideoRecorder.cs class via email

Comment: @NikS I am interested how did you do it?

Comment: @Umar Let me know how I can send you files

Comment: @NikS why don't you share it somewhere on web and share link here? It willl be beneficial for everyone :)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VEa3yNGF - this is VideoRecorder interface to simplify VideoRecorder replacement

Comment: https://pastebin.com/N6PC65sQ - this is first implementation of VideoRecorder using AForge.Video
I faced with some issue in first implementation related to often video start/stop.
https://pastebin.com/xq0Cd4RE - So this is the second implementation of VideoRecorder using AForge.Video with fixed start/stop bug. I have no issue with this one.
https://pastebin.com/4LDrfuHn - And here is example of VideoRecorder usage. I've created BaseFixture. All my TestFixtures inherit this one. I am recording separate video for every tests so i've put start/stop to Setup/TearDown methods

Comment: @NikS What is the exact dll name that you used

Comment: AForge.Video.dll and AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll

Answer (score 0):

Both

rylstim: http://www.sketchman-studio.com/rylstim-screen-recorder/

and camStudio: http://camstudio.org/

are free and easy to use tools to record the screen.  Depending on how much automation you need,  I also use AutoHotkey to launch such external tools since I find the API much more power than trying to send keystrokes using NUnit, but this may be more sophistication than you need.

Comment: is there a programming way?