# Selenium C# - Recording how chrome driver do a test case

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

At this moment, in my tests I use Screenshots to locate where my test failed.. Screenshot is only taken while, test fails.
Sometimes it is difficult to find a place where the test failed exactly. That's why I am thinking about start recording chrome driver's work. I could take failed tests, take their records/videos and check on the screen through video what was wrong in each failed case.

I found some solutions that won't work today, for example:

- [Screen Recorder](https://medium.com/maestral-solutions/setup-automation-test-screen-recorder-with-selenium-webdriver-and-c-aee8b6d1ba9b) - there is no available Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 today.
- Some solutions have problems with Headless mode.

I want to start recording after create chrome driver (in each test case), than through test's steps and stop recording on the end of each test case. I am going to check result of test case (Failed, Blocked, PASS). Than I am going to save video (in any location) if test failed/blocked and delete the video if test case PASSED.

Do you have any ideas to record driver's work ?

Comment: [How to Record test execution using Selenium C# in .NetCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424616/how-to-record-test-execution-using-selenium-c-sharp-in-netcore) - Screen capturing won't work headless, though I am surprised that anything would work with headless mode.